# Error using mongosh give error MongoBulkWriteError

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I connect Mongodb of COsmoDB , version 3.6., below the comand:

```
mongosh.exe url:10255 -u user -p pawss --tls --sslAllowInvalidCertificates@echo on
```

then use o comand of insert show error:

```
db.xxxxxxx.insert({({"num_id":NumberLong(2),
```

give error:

```
. MongoBulkWriteError: Retryable writes are not supported. Please disable retryable writes by specifying "retrywrites=false" in the connection string or an equivalent driver specific config. globaldb [direct: primary]> (To exit, press Ctrl+C again or Ctrl+D or type .exit) globaldb [direct: primary]>
```

Comment: According to the error message, and did you try to add `--retryWrites false` in your connect command?

Answer (score 0):

To sum up here. According to the error message,  add `--retryWrites false` into connect command can solve the problem.